# How to edit mem file in FoxPro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a `mem` file called `girot.mem`. It has the name to change program caption, how to change or edit the `girot.mem`? Here is the `girot.mem` file :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/90i4ob3g5j0kkgh/girot.mem?dl=0

The name I want change or edit in `mem` file is `zoom` to `abcd`. each time I change it using notepad, the `exe` file won't run.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad has nothing to do with a mem file which is a binary file.

You edit a men file using restore and save commands. i.e.: Assuming your variable's name is myVar:

```
clear all
restore from girot.mem
myVar = "abcd"
save to girot.mem
```

If you would anyway use something external then use a hex editor or a language with commands to read and write binary, not notepad.

Comment: Sorry I still newbie, can u send some sample?

Comment: You didn't understand me, notepad, notepad++, sciText, sublime text, vs code ... are not suitable editors for editing a mem file. You should use your VFP IDE and commands. If you don't have VFP, ask help from someone near you who has it.

Comment: I downloaded your griot.mem. It had m.vabatang variable with value "Z  O  O  M" in it. I edited it to be "a  b  c  d" instead. If you give me an email address I would post edited girot.mem file there.